# Azure: Unable to connect to cluster (Aks-engine) using kubectl

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

---

**SOLUTION**

I appended feature-gates in kube-apiserver.yaml in master node. This broke the apiserver, so kubectl couldn't connect to the nodes. After removing them, it was working fine.

---

**PROBLEM**

I deployed a Kubernetes cluster using aks-engine but I'm getting this error `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 13.66.162.75:443: i/o timeout` when I try to use kubectl. I'm able to access the master node with the serial console but not through ssh (same error comes in this case).

```
$ KUBECONFIG=_output/kubeconfig/kubeconfig.westus2.json kubectl get node
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 13.66.162.75:443: i/o timeout


$ KUBECONFIG=_output/kubeconfig/kubeconfig.westus2.json kubectl version
    Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.6", GitCommit:"6260bb08c46c31eea6cb538b34a9ceb3e406689c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-21T06:34:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Aks-Engine version - `v0.28.1-linux-amd64`

Kubernetes version - `1.10.12`

Here is the kubeconfig.westus2.json file -

```
  {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "clusters": [
            {
                "cluster": {
                    "certificate-authority-data": "*****"
                    "server": "https://masquerade-az.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com"
                },
                "name": "masquerade-az"
            }
        ],
        "contexts": [
            {
                "context": {
                    "cluster": "masquerade-az",
                    "user": "masquerade-az-admin"
                },
                "name": "masquerade-az"
            }
        ],
        "current-context": "masquerade-az",
        "kind": "Config",
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "masquerade-az-admin",
                "user": {"client-certificate-data":"****","client-key-data":"*****"}
            }
        ]
    }
```

[This](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23634977/52162658-54097c80-26fd-11e9-9ad2-8ef678eed81c.png) is the screenshots for inbound ports.

[This](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23634977/52162665-697ea680-26fd-11e9-8190-dff7f03c667f.png) is the screenshot for outbound ports.

Comment: I have already looked at various issues opened on StackOverflow and Github and still wasn't able to solve it.

Comment: is the deployment successful?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes, I'm able to access and run VM using Serial console on Azure portal.

Comment: that doesnt mean its successful

Comment: @4c74356b41 These were the logs when I deployed it using aks-engine. It shows the deployment succeeded



`WARN[0003] apimodel: missing masterProfile.dnsPrefix will use "masquerade-az" 
WARN[0003] --resource-group was not specified. Using the DNS prefix from the apimodel as the resource group name: masquerade-az 
INFO[0014] Starting ARM Deployment (masquerade-az-191452406). This will take some time... 
INFO[0547] Finished ARM Deployment (masquerade-az-191452406). Succeeded`

Comment: should be fine. but not sure about the dns warning. I don't think it's actually exposed. looks like you need to give it dns prefix when deploying. or after in your kubernetes config give it proper address. as that dnsname won't resolve, obviously

Comment: @4c74356b41 I followed https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/tutorials/deploy.md to deploy the cluster. There it's written that `The DNS prefix must be unique so pick a random name.` and the same warning is present even in the sample deployment.

Comment: I suspect you need to provide dns prefix or edit your config file to point to the servers. not sure that is the real name

Comment: @4c74356b41 Okay thnx, I'll try recreating the cluster with a different dns prefix.

Comment: ok, please get back when you have results ;)

Comment: Any update? did that work for you?

Comment: @KarishmaTiwari-MSFT I appended feature-gates in `kube-apiserver.yaml` in master node. This broke the `apiserver`, so kubectl couldn't connect to the nodes. After removing them, it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As shared by the original poster, the solution is:

I appended feature-gates in kube-apiserver.yaml in master node. This broke the apiserver, so kubectl couldn't connect to the nodes. After removing them, it was working fine.